# Length mismatch: Expected axis has 218 elements, new values have 230 elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have been accessing a pandas data frame, and an error is keeps popping up.

```
cases_expand = []

for case in cases_II:
    output = case[-1][0]
    month = case[-1][1]
    features = [v[0] for v in case[0:-1]] + [month] + [output]
    cases_expand.append(features)

feat = ["h_", "r_", "in_Umiray_", "in_Angat_", "out_NIA_", "out_MWSS_"]

cases_df2 = pd.DataFrame(cases_expand)

col_names = []
for f in feat:
    if f != "out_NIA_" and f != "out_MWSS_":
        for i in range(batch_size):
            col_names.append(f+str(i+1))
    else:
        for i in range(look_back + batch_size):
            col_names.append(f+str(i+1))

col_names += ["month", "output"]

#print (col_names)
cases_df2.columns = col_names
print (col_names)
```

The error is:

> Length mismatch: Expected axis has 218 elements. New values has 230 elements.

Comment: The error i am getting is the one in the subject matter. Length mismatch: Expected axis has 218 elements. New values has 230 elements.

Comment: Why don't you add the error in your post?